# How do I escape multiple query params for an IN() clause?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am trying to perform a `SELECT` query with an `IN()` clause, and have sqlalchemy perform the
parameter escaping for me. I am using pyodbc as my database connector.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
tables = ['table1', 'table2', ... ]
sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN(:tables)"
result = session.execute(sql, {"tables": tables})
```

Unfortunatenly this fails with an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=list', 'HY105')
```

Is there any way I can have sqlalchemy escape the whole list of parameters and join them with `,`
without manually adding a `:tableX` placeholder for each item of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
DECLARE @string Varchar(100) = 'Table1,table2,table3'

  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@string,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'


SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN(  select
                     r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
                    from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For good reasons it is not possible to expand a list of arguments as you wish.

If you really would like to create a *raw* `SQL query`, then you can just enumerate over your list and dynamically create the query:

```
vals = {"param{}".format(i): table for i, table in enumerate(tables)}
keys = ", ".join([":{}".format(k) for k in vals])
sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ({keys})".format(keys=keys)
result = session.execute(sql, vals)

for tbl in result:
    print(tbl)
```

But you could ask `sqlalchemy` to do this for you. Here we make a *fake* mapping of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` view, and query it using `sqlalchemy` toolset:

```
# definition (done just once)
class ISTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tables'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'}
    _fake_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_catalog = Column(String)
    table_schema = Column(String)
    table_name = Column(String)
    table_type = Column(String)

# actual usage
result = session.query(
    ISTable.table_catalog, ISTable.table_schema,
    ISTable.table_name, ISTable.table_type,
).filter(
    ISTable.table_name.in_(tables))

for tbl in result:
    print(tbl)
```

One gotcha: you cannot query for the whole mapped class (like this `query(ISTable)`) because the `primary_key` does not exist and an exception will be raised. But querying only columns we can about (as shown above) is good enough for the purpose.